# How to make interactive highchart tooltips

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I ran into highchart tooltips that have clickable elements in them. The problem is that you can't click those reliably.

Increasing `tooltip.hideDelay` makes it easier to click inside the tooltip. That doesn't solve the problem completely.

I want to be able to hover and click inside the tooltip for as long as I want. It should only be dismissed when the mouse pointer leaves the tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to set a very long timeout for hiding of the tooltip. While handling some of the hover logic myself to dismiss it.

```
    Highcharts.chart('my_chart', {
        tooltip: {
            // Show the tooltip for a really long time
            hideDelay: 9999999
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                events: {
                    mouseOver: function () {
                        // Restore the tooltip after hiding
                        // that's done in mouseOut
                        if (this.chart.tooltip.label) {
                            var show = this.chart.tooltip.label.show
                                    .bind(this.chart.tooltip.label);
                            show();
                        }
                    },
                    mouseOut: function () {
                        // Get a hold of the tooltip and hide it
                        // on "mouseout"
                        var label = this.chart.tooltip.label,
                            div = $(label.div),
                            hide = label.hide
                                .bind(label);

                        div.on('mouseenter', function () {
                            div.on('mouseleave', function () {
                                hide();
                                div.off('mouseleave');
                            });
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
    });
```

One drawback I can think of is that the tooltip will stick. Unless you hover it at any point in time. Or hover another higchart series. You can add a listener to the body on *click* outside of any tooltip to dismiss any lingering ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can also wrap `runPointActions` function of Pointer prototype to prevent displaying tooltip on mouseOver, while tooltip exists and call `Tooltip.refresh` function on point click. This way tooltip will not show in a different place on a chart, until specific point is click.

DOCS Reference:
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.point.events.click

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/0xvmLLfd/